# GridLayout and boxes centred using weights

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to produce 4 equal boxes in the centre using a GridLayout but I'm getting the following instead:

[image]

I must be doing something wrong. Shouldn't my code at least fill the screen though? Here's my code:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnCount="8"
            android:rowCount="8">

    <Button
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:layout_rowSpan="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="4"
            android:layout_columnWeight="4"
            android:text="1" />

    <Button
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:layout_rowSpan="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="4"
            android:layout_columnWeight="4"
            android:text="2" />

    <Button
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:layout_rowSpan="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="4"
            android:layout_columnWeight="4"
            android:text="3" />

    <Button
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:layout_rowSpan="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="4"
            android:layout_columnWeight="4"
            android:text="4" />
</GridLayout>
```

Does anyone know what might be missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using weight sum yet?

Comment: You mean in an outer layout, e.g., LinearLayout? No, I'd try to avoid nesting weights.

Comment: I suggest you should do the other layout.

Comment: What do you mean by the other layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PercentRelativeLayout does the trick very nicely:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/button_s"
                app:layout_widthPercent="30%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="30%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="10%"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="15%"
                app:layout_marginRightPercent="5%"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/button_c"
                app:layout_widthPercent="30%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="30%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="10%"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
                app:layout_marginRightPercent="15%"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_s"/>

        <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/button_r"
                app:layout_widthPercent="30%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="30%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="10%"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="15%"
                app:layout_marginRightPercent="5%"
                android:layout_below="@id/button_s"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_widthPercent="30%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="30%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="10%"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
                app:layout_marginRightPercent="15%"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_r"
                android:layout_below="@id/button_c"/>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve:

- putting the buttons in the center of their cell, add

  ```
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  ```
- filling the available space, add

  ```
  android:layout_gravity="fill"
  ```

See [`android:layout_gravity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity) for details. You can combine this with [`ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html).